# Tag Data standards in user memory for RFID 13.56 MHz frequency and ISO/IEC 14443

Tags: nfc, rfid

The Gen 2 RFID tags support the EPC Tag Data Standard. This contains standards for storing supplementary GS1 data in common fields such as Batch/Lot Number, Due Date, Expiration date.

I am curious whether there are any similar "tag data" standards for the user memory of HF RFID tags with (13.56 MHz center frequency) and specifically those which are ISO/IEC 14443 compliant?  User memory refers to the areas in a tag which contains the actual data.  For example, in an NTAG-215 or MiFARE MF0UL21 tag there is a user memory from page 4 onwards.

Basically, I'm interested in a standards-based approach for storing data in the user memory area such as batch/lot number and expiration data in a ISO/IEC 14443 compliant tag?   Does such as standard exist? Or it is more common to store data in proprietary form?

Answer (score 0):

The air interface etc. of the standard concerning the item management that you are about to use is ISO/IEC 18000.
RFID at 13.56 MHz is defined in ISO/IEC 18000-3.

As described in Wikipedia as "The German identity card contains an ISO/IEC 18000-3 and ISO/IEC 14443 type A compatible 13.56 MHz RFID chip that uses the ISO/IEC 7816 protocols.". It seems that it is not difficult to respond to both standards.

Similar to "EPC Tag Data Standard" is specified in ISO/IEC 15961,15962,15963.

I do not know whether 13.56 MHz RFID tags can be used equally as Gen 2 RFID tags, but I hope that this information will be useful to you.

Comment: I think what I'm after is ISO/IEC 15962:2013 which according to https://www.iso.org/standard/43459.html defines the encoded structure of object identifiers.

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comment 15962:2013 looks applicable.  I'm trying to understand what approaches are used for NTAG/MiFARE for storing user data similar to the example here http://www.kentraub.net/tools/tagxlate/EPCEncoderDecoder.html for EPC tag data.